# Need to create a dynamic script in Jmeter for adding an item to cart and then performing checkout

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I have recorded the script using blazemeter and then exported it to the Jmeter.

I'm already doing the login from csv file, but I also wanted to make the process of selecting item, adding to cart and checkout as dynamic. I wanted to handle the dynamically for token, product id , and other values.

Below is my current code for reference.

1. Select the item
   [image]
2. Add item to cart
   [image]
3. Check out process
   [image]

Could please someone help me make this code dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters, it assumes:

1. Extracting the dynamic values from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Saving the dynamic values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Replacing recorded hard-coded values with the variables containing dynamic values.

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

If you're uncertain regarding which values need to be correlated - record the same test scenario twice and compare resulting [.jmx test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) - all the values which will differ are a subject for correlation.